# unable to access protected array and print

Tags: discussion

I'm facing an issue in getting data from the protected array and echo in PHP. I have attached my sample protected array below.

```
(1) {
["_data":protected]=>
    array(2) {
    ["attribute_code"]=>
    string(11) "description"
    ["value"]=>
    string(14) "My Custom desc"
    }
}

//not working
$customAttribute = $customAttributes["_data"]["value"];
echo $customAttribute;
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's belong to stackoverflow.com